# I'm struggling with my If-statement using Atoi

Tags: c++, if-statement, atoi

I'm trying to make a ticket customer code, and I'm currently working with displaying my "customers". I want it to be like, if i type "blank, like nothing then enter" I want all of my customers in my own DTA file to be on my output. In other words displayed, to see which customers are registered.

```
void Customer::DisplayCustomer() {
    cin.getline(buffer, MAXTEXT)
    buffernr = atoi(buffer)   //I need to convert text to numbers. 

    if (buffer[0]=='A' && buffer[1] == '\0')
    // (Here I have a function which displays everything) don't focus on this one
}
```

What I'm asking is, what do i have to type, in order for my code to understand that I want to have a if statement for someone who presses Enter without typing anything my display customer function will run. I've also tried (If buffer[0]=='\n') but that won't work either.

Comment: You usually would use something like `std::getline(std::cin,buffer)`.

Comment: i have done done using namespase std;

Comment: What does this have to do with `atoi`?

Comment: You need `buffer[0] == '\0'` to check if the buffer is empty

Comment: If you press Enter (no other data entered) you will have an empty buffer, so no need to call `atoi` if you check for this condition first.

Comment: If you want to find a custommer by it's custommer number, you type it's number to find it, or you can type in the custommer's name to find it. I can't post my whole code because then my post will be deleted.

What I'm asking is, what do I need in my IF-statement to make it understand that I want to have a statement that the user can simply type Nothing, just press enter. And it will understand that it is asking for a function that I have made later on

Comment: Yeah now we are getting somewhere! So if my buffer is empty, it is buffer[0]=='\0' then it understand it is empty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code checks if the buffer is empty

```
#include <iostream>

int MAXTEXT{300};

int main() {
    char buffer[MAXTEXT];
    std::cin.getline(buffer, MAXTEXT);
    if (buffer[0] == '\0') {
        std::cout << "Empty" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A better solutions with `std::string` is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string buffer;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    if (buffer.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Empty" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a `std::string` object, why bother with NUL terminators?

Comment: Okey, thank you so much for showing me. This is the answer I needed. I will mark this as answer.

Comment: I'm not very skilled programmer, I only know this way. Do you think it is pointless to use Atoi?

Comment: @Lillie I don't know what you are doing with `buffernr` so I can't say. Do you use it somewhere later?

Comment: Yeah, buffernr I use in order to find my custommers by using their numbers. Every custommer has their own ID. That is not my issue this in case, but I do appriciate that you tell me this. My code is working :)

Comment: You should check the return value of [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). CTRL+D will cause a failure.

Comment: @jww Why? It returns a reference to `std::cin`. What can I check there?

Comment: @jww That's not the question. The question was, how to check if the string is empty. I'm not going to modify OP's whole code. I'm just answering the question. My answer is `buffer[0] == '\0'` resp. `buffer.empty()`. The rest is an example to demonstrate. Nobody asked how to read lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use `std::getline()` rather than `std::istream::getline()` for your use case:

```
void Customer::DisplayCustomer() {
    std::string buffer;
    std::getline(std:cin,buffer);
    std::istringstream iss(buffer);
    int buffernr;
    if(!(iss >> buffernr)) { // This condition would be false if there's no numeric value
                             // has been entered from the standard input
                             // including a simple ENTER (i.e. buffer was empty)
         // (Here i have a function which displays everything) don't focus on this 
         //  one
    }
    else {
        // Use buffernr as it was parsed correctly from input
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Iss? Never seen this before.

Comment: @Lillie _"What is Iss?"_ It's an instance of [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). Appreciate to teach you something new.

Comment: @Lillie I added some comments in my code proposal to clarify. You should consider to use this as a more general solution. There's no need for `atoi()` at all,

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try to make my code like this. This is very appriciated.